# How can you make dynamically added content in JQuery appear?

Tags: jquery

The following code changes a `div` with the id `#CommentLikeDisplay` which previously had been set to `display:none` to `display:block` when one clicks a "like" button (`.LikeCommentLink`). There are multiple like buttons on the page, and the code works perfectly, except for when the elements `CommentLikeDisplay` and `LikeCommentLink` are added dynamically with JQuery (they are both added as part of the same dynamically added comment, which isn't relevant). I don't understand, because even when the elements are dynamically added, the line `$("#LikeCommentLink" + myNumber).css("color", "#2078F4");` works perfectly, yet it can't make the div with `display:none` appear. I checked in Google Developer Tools and the code does indeed change the element to `display:block` when I click the button, but the `div` still isn't appearing, and I have no idea why that is the case. As you can see, I have tried two different methods to change the div's style to `display:block`, which does actually work in the code but not on the screen. However, as I said, the whole thing works when the elements are not dynamically added.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
$("#NewsfeedContainer").on('click', '.LikeCommentLink', function(event){ //comment or subcomment LIKE button clicked
            
            let myID = $( this ).attr("id");

            let myNumber = myID.substring(15);

            $("#LikeCommentLink" + myNumber).css("color", "#2078F4");

            $('#CommentLikeDisplay' + myNumber).addClass('CommentLikeDisplay_is_shown');

            $("#CommentLikeDisplay" + myNumber).css("display", "block");
});


The following is how I create the HTML, which is inserted via JQuery and works fine.

toInsert += "<span class = 'LikeCommentLink'  data-wall_id = '" + wall_id + "' id = 'LikeCommentLink" + response[0].new_post_id + "' data-post_author_id = '" + PostAuthorID + "'>Like</span>";                                 

toInsert +=  
"<div class = 'CommentLikeDisplay' id = 'CommentLikeDisplay" + response[0].new_post_id + "'>";

toInsert += "<img src = 'images/bluelike.png' />"

toInsert += "<div class = 'CommentLikeDisplayNumber' id = 'CommentLikeDisplayNumber" + response[0].new_post_id + "'>0</div>";      

toInsert += "</div>";
```

Comment: Can you show how you created those elements dynamically?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code?

Comment: @prettyInPink  I just showed how I created the HTML elements dynamically. Thank you!

Comment: @JoseLora  I just showed how I created the HTML elements dynamically. Thank you!

Comment: You say, I can see ```display:block``` applied to the element. What do you see in the styles tab itself for the element in the dev tools?

Comment: Also, what happens if you simply set ```.CommentLikeDisplayNumber``` in your styles to ```display:none;``` and for the class added ```.CommentLikeDisplay_is_shown``` styles should be ```diplay:block;```. This should be enough.

Comment: @prettyInPink Thank you very much, your answer worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see it works fine in this example with dynamic element.

```js
let uniqueID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
let likeComment = `<span class="LikeCommentLink" id="like-${uniqueID}">Like Comment</span>`;
let likeCommentResponse = `<div class="CommentLikeDisplayNumber" id="CommentLikeDisplay${uniqueID}">Comment Liked</div>`;
$('#NewsfeedContainer').append(likeComment);
$('#NewsfeedContainer').append(likeCommentResponse);

$('#NewsfeedContainer').on('click','.LikeCommentLink', function() {
  $('#CommentLikeDisplay'+$(this).attr('id').substring(5)).addClass('CommentLikeDisplay_is_shown');
});
```

```css
.CommentLikeDisplayNumber {
  display: none;
}

.CommentLikeDisplay_is_shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NewsfeedContainer"></div>
```